# Time complexity of scipy.null_space()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following snippet of code:

```
(... some previous code ...)

vecs = np.array(vecs_list, dtype=int)

kernel = scipy.linalg.null_space(np.transpose(vecs))
rows, columns = kernel.shape

(... some ensuing code ...)
```

Let me clarify some things:

- `vecs_list` : is a list of *L* lists each with size *s*. I like to think of it as an *L*x*s* matrix.
- there **is** a reason as to why I start with a list and then make the conversion to a np.array (this relates to the nature of the prior code, but the object that we start from really must be a list of lists!).

My question is the following: what is the time complexity of this snippet of code as it stands?

---

The way I see it the answer goes something like this:

- `vecs = np.array(vecs_list, dtype=int)` : might take *O(s***L)* time
- `np.transpose(vecs)` : *O(1)* time
- `scipy.linalg.null_space(*)` : uses SVD but I am not entirely certain what that means for the time complexity. I suppose I would expect *O(n^3)* for an *n*x*n* matrix but here the matrix is not a square matrix and I am not sure of the implications. Do you know what is the time complexity of this method? Is there a better alternative from the big-*O* point of view?
- `kernel.shape` : *O(1)* time

---

Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT:** After some quick studies where I varied *s* and *L* separately, I got the following graphs:
[image]

[image]

which seems to suggest that *O(s^2 L^2)*. This is a bit disturbing because it indicated that if *s=L* then *O(s^4)* instead of the *O(s^3)* that one would expect. Any thoughts about this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you actually need `kernel`, or do you just want its dimensions?

Comment: Check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649587/time-complexity-of-finding-nullspace-of-a-matrix

Comment: I will `kernel` need it further below in the code (besides the dimensions, of course).

Comment: I had checked that link. Two problems: (1) it discusses only square n by n matrices (which is not necessarily my case), (2) it does not discuss specifically the scipy.linalg.null_space implementation. I want to make sure about the complexity of that specific scipy method.

Comment: roughly what's (l,s) dimensions?

Comment: @hpaulj do you mean the usual numeric values for *L* and *s*? If so they can be anything from 1 to 1000, though generally L < s.